# bash for loop not searching characters

Tags: bash

hey guy I have this for loop that checks to make sure that a string only has '#' and " " in it. If it only contains these two characters is echos out yes and if not it echos out no.

```
string="###############
    #             #
    # #############
    #             #
    # ######### # #
    #         # # #
    # ### ##### # #
    #   #     # # #
    # # ###########
    # #            
    ###############"

confirm_variable="Yes"
for (( i=0; i<${#string}; i++ )); do
str="${string:$i:1}"
    if [ "$str" == "#" ] || [ "$str" == " " ] || [ "$str" == "\n" ]; 
        then
            continue
        else
            confirm_variable="No"
            break
    fi

done
echo $confirm_variable
```

not sure why this isn't working as it is mean to because if I try it with the string "### ###  #### # ##" it works hows it meant too

Comment: Your test string contains linebreak characters as well

Comment: @MikaelÖhman how can I fix this issue?

Comment: I cleaned up the tags.  This is an issue with the bash language itself, not relevant to the OS it's running on, and certainly not relevant to Linux kernel programming.

Answer (score 0):

Linebreak are a bit tricky. You have 3 options

1. For bash (might not work in other shells), you can do `[ "$str" = $'\n' ]`
2. You can do

```sh
newline='
'
... [ "$str" == "$newline" ] ...
```

3. Enter the linebreak directly (quite ugly)

```
... [ "$str" == '
' ] ...
```

Comment: thank you it works,  why is there a difference between using "\n" and  '\n' ?

Comment: The difference is with the special bash syntax `$'\n'`. The `$` in front evaluates the escaped character. Try yourself `echo '\n'` vs `echo $'\n'`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way with bash.
No need of loop

```
cat le_script
#!/bin/bash
! [ "$1" ] && { echo "No" ; exit ; }
string="${1//#}"
string="${string// }"
string="${string//$'\n'}"
[ "$string" ] && echo "No" || echo "Yes"
```

and call it this way :

```
./le_script "$string"
```